# At the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory: What does .distUpgrade really mean?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, ppa

At the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory exists the following files

```
docker.list              git-core-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list              google-chrome.list
docker.list.distUpgrade  git-core-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade  mysql.list
```

What does `.distUpgrade` mean?

I assumed it was because through `Virtual Box` I did do an upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 but why for `mysql.list` does not exist the `mysql.list.distUpgrade` file? Same for case `google-chrome.list` file

Now more, about docker the files content are equals

```
cat docker.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable

cat docker.list.distUpgrade 
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   focal stable
```

But is not the same for git

```
cat git-core-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy main # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main

cat git-core-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list.distUpgrade 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal main
```

**Goal**

Do an upgrade about `focal` to `jammy` and I found this situation

For mysql was easier (already upgraded)

```
cat mysql.list 
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out entries below, but any other modifications may be lost.
# Use command 'dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config' as root for modifications.
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0
```

Here for Google

```
cat google-chrome.list 
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Nothing to upgrade (nothing about either focal or jammy), not sure how common is this